# Transliteration from Ethiopic (and others) to ASCII (ሀ -> ha; ü -> ue)

Tags: utf-8, transliteration

I am not yet so good with reading Amharic (Geez / Ethiopic) letters.

If I have a text in Ge'ez (Ethiopia) letters ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%27ez_language ) I want to transliterate them to ASCII.

When I go with the LYNX Textmode browser to http://www.addismap.com/am/ (webpage in Amharic) it showes me "edis map: yeedis ebeba karta". How can I access this functionality for example in Python, Bash or PHP? Which API do they use?

It seems not to be iconv:

```
$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
Input:    ሀ ለ ሐ መ ሠ ረ ሰ
Output:   ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICU http://icu-project.org/ has an Amharic-Latin transform, which will turn your text into "hā le ḥā me še re se". You could use this using `uconv -x 'Amharic/BGN-Latin'` from the command line, or use [pyicu](http://pyicu.osafoundation.org).

Answer (score 0):

The [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/) defines some transliterations.  [Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/Text-Unidecode-0.04/lib/Text/Unidecode.pm) (or its [Python port](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1)) has even more of them.

Comment: CLDR doesn't (yet) have that script, however.